# Left justify parts of resume using res.cls

Tags: horizontal-alignment, resume

I'm creating a resume using the [`res.cls` package](http://www.math.nyu.edu/student_resources/res.cls) and I'm using the `margin` style option, which specifies that section titles are to the left of the body text.  This essentially makes it look like there are two columns -- the left column where the section titles are and the right where the body is.  This is fine for most of the resume, however, in certain places, I would like to have the body text be all the way to the left of the page.  For example, I want a line which says "This information is current as of DATE", justified to the left of the page, not just the left of the body column.  Does anyone know how I can do this?

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}
\oddsidemargin -.5in
\evensidemargin -.5in
\textwidth=6.0in
\itemsep=0in
\parsep=0in
\newenvironment{list1}
  {\begin{list}{\ding{113}}{%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
    \setlength{\parsep}{0in}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
    \setlength{\topsep}{0in}
    \setlength{\partopsep}{0in}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.17in}}}
  {\end{list}}
\newenvironment{list2}
  {\begin{list}{$\bullet$}{%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
    \setlength{\parsep}{0in}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
    \setlength{\topsep}{0in}
    \setlength{\partopsep}{0in}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.2in}}}
  {\end{list}}
\begin{document}
\name{Name \vspace*{.1in}}
\begin{resume}
\section{\sc Research Interests}
Bayesian statistics, spatial and spatio-temporal statistics, 
statistical methods for environmental and public health data, 
statistical computing, statistical methods for large datasets. 
{Current information as of May 2012}
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Also, here is a link to the template I'm using: http://biosun1.harvard.edu/~paciorek/computingTips/Latex_template_creating_CV_.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For small parts pushed flush with the left margin, you could just use a negative horizontal space. The width of the section title is given by `\sectionwidth`, so using

```
\hspace*{-\sectionwidth}<your content>
```

works. Here's your MWE with this adjustment included:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}
\oddsidemargin -.5in
\evensidemargin -.5in
\textwidth=6.0in
\itemsep=0in
\parsep=0in
\newenvironment{list1}
  {\begin{list}{\ding{113}}{%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
    \setlength{\parsep}{0in}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
    \setlength{\topsep}{0in}
    \setlength{\partopsep}{0in}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.17in}}}
  {\end{list}}
\newenvironment{list2}
  {\begin{list}{$\bullet$}{%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
    \setlength{\parsep}{0in}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
    \setlength{\topsep}{0in}
    \setlength{\partopsep}{0in}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.2in}}}
  {\end{list}}
\begin{document}
\name{Name \vspace*{.1in}}
\begin{resume}
\section{\sc Research Interests}
Bayesian statistics, spatial and spatio-temporal statistics, 
statistical methods for environmental and public health data, 
statistical computing, statistical methods for large datasets.

\hspace*{-\sectionwidth}Current information as of May 2012.
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```