# Left justify \dates for res.cls

Tags: horizontal-alignment, resume

This is an extension of the question posed: [Left justify parts of resume using res.cls](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57219/left-justify-parts-of-resume-using-res-cls)

mwe:

```
\documentclass[margin, 10pt]{res}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{\large\bf Bob Lob La} % Your name at the top

\begin{document}
\begin{resume}

\section{EXPERIENCE}
{\bf Ditch digger} \hfill November 2009 - Present \\
Barnies bigger diggers

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Produces the following. 
[image]
The question is, can I move the dates to be underneath the Section Title, *without* any forced line breaks? The solution to the above question, which would be something like adding

```
\hspace*{-\sectionwidth}November 2009 - Present
```

causes a newline between the dates and the description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand correctly.

Do you mean something like this?

> [image]

```
\documentclass[margin]{res}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{\large\bfseries Bob Lob La} % Your name at the top

\begin{document}
\begin{resume}

\section{EXPERIENCE \\ \textmd{November 2009 - Present}}
\textbf{Ditch digger} \\ Barnies bigger diggers

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I mean something exactly like that. Very clever approach. Then, for multiple date descriptions below each section I will just insert the dates as sections.

Comment: @phil0stine Happy to have helped. P.S. if you need more space between the section title and the rest you can add something like `\addtolength{\sectionwidth}{25pt}`.