# Column numbering for cv

Tags: numbering, columns

[image]

For the resume I need to add the refrees in two coloumns with numbering which is shown below. I am using **res.cls** . How can I do that? anybody please help
  [image]

Comment: Related: [Separate columns with text in different text in each column](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/337853/5764)

Comment: It would be great if you could show some effort and include a minimal document we can work with.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following would suffice:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin,10pt]{res}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\name{A Person}
\opening

\hspace*{-\sectionwidth}%
\makebox[\dimexpr\sectionwidth+\linewidth]{\begin{tabular}[t]{ l }
  \makebox[0pt][r]{1. }First Person \\
  address line 1 \\
  address line 2
\end{tabular}\hspace{.25\linewidth}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{ l }
  \makebox[0pt][r]{2. }Second Person \\
  phone number \\
  email address
\end{tabular}}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```